# Titanium webview rendering incorrectly on Android 5

Tags: webview, titanium

My android phone (Samsung Galaxy S5, AT&T) just updated from Android 4.4 to 5.0 and now rendering of webviews in Titanium is not working. I have a published app that worked fine on Android 4.4, and now does not render correctly in 5.0 (same phone, no app code changes). Specifically, it seems the window is automatically having a huge height and width to its default canvas (at least 4 times the screen size), and word-wrapping and formatting of divs to absolute positions are not working. Previously, the canvas was the width of the screen so that word-wrapping would occur, and the height of the window was the height of the content in the window. I've reproduced the error on my phone with the below Alloy code:

```
<Alloy>
<Window title="Test">
<WebView id="web1" html="<html><head></head><body><p>This is a long paragraph that should have word wrap once it reaches the right side of the screen, but unfortunately the new version of Android seems to be preventing this behavior, which is peculiar, as issues did not arise with prior versions of Android, as far as I can tell.</p></body</html>" class="webclass" backgroundColor="transparent" />
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the below code to each HTML file seems to create a consistent rendering of HTML in various versions of Android, and ensure screen width is appropriate:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I searched a lot and I found that it depends on the running OS on the device.

Try to add this code in the `js` file, it won't solve the problem but it should do word-wrapping and zoom in.

```
var htmlText = "<p>This is a long paragraph that should have word wrap once it reaches the right side of the screen, but unfortunately the new version of Android seems to be preventing this behavior, which is peculiar, as issues did not arise with prior versions of Android, as far as I can tell.</p>"

if(OS_ANDROID) htmlText = '<html><body><div style="width:' + 
        (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth - 20) + 'px; height:auto;">' + 
        htmlText + '</div></body></html>';
$.webView.html = htmlText;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but for some reason this isn't working for me either. I'm not getting any error codes at all... for some reason it's not word-wrapping properly, even with this CSS width (the text is about 2.5x wider than the screen before it randomly wraps).